# Python change the function to compute for an array

Tags: python, arrays, function, output

I have an example csv file with name 'r2.csv':

```
Factory | Product_Number |   Date     |   mu   |   cs   |  co 
--------------------------------------------------------------
   A    |      1         | 01APR2017  |   5.6  |  125   |  275
--------------------------------------------------------------
   A    |      1         | 02APR2017  |   4.5  |  200   |  300
--------------------------------------------------------------
   A    |      1         | 03APR2017  |   6.6  |  150   |  250
--------------------------------------------------------------
   A    |      1         | 04APR2017  |   7.5  |  175   |  325
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

With the following code I have:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import poisson, norm
import csv

# Read Data
with open('r2.csv', 'r') as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    data = {}
    for row in reader:
        for header, value in row.items():
            try:
                data[header].append(value)
            except KeyError:
                data[header] = [value]

# To create a list for the following parameters 
mu = data['mu']
cs = data['cs']
co = data['co']

# Convert data type to 'float' 
mu = map(float,mu)  
cs = map(float,cs)  
co = map(float,co)

Order_Number = map(lambda mu_,cs_,co_:np.ceil(poisson.ppf(co_/(cs_+co_),mu_)),mu,cs,co)
```

The code works fine. And if I would like to define a function that can work for an array as you suggested above.

```
G = poisson(mu) 
p = G.pmf(np.arange(3*mu)) 

def Z(Q): 
    for i in range(len(p)): 
        yield p[i]*cs*max((Q-i), 0) + p[i]*co*max((i-Q), 0)
```

It has error message if I try to run it. **ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar. ** Thanks!

Besides, if I want to store each pair of (Q, sum(Z(Q))) for each single line, how could I do it? As each line data has multiple (Q, sum(Z(Q)); 
Let Cost = sum(Z(Q)) and additional column names are Q = 0, 1, 2, ...; values are Cost, which is sum(Z(Q))

Output file looks like:

```
Factory | Product_Number |   Date     |   mu   |   cs   |  co | Q=0 | Q=1 | ... | Q = 30 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   A    |      1         | 01APR2017  |   5.6  |  125   | 275 |Cost |Cost |.....| Cost 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   A    |      1         | 02APR2017  |   4.5  |  200   |  300|Cost |Cost |.....| Cost 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   A    |      1         | 03APR2017  |   6.6  |  150   |  250|Cost |Cost |.....| Cost 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   A    |      1         | 04APR2017  |   7.5  |  175   |  325|Cost |Cost |.....| Cost 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As the following code runs okay if input only has one line data, but not useful for multiple lines or arrays.

```
with open('output2.csv', 'wb') as fq:
     csv_writer = csv.writer(fq, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n', )
     csv_writer.writerow(("Order_Number", "Cost Expectation"))
         for Q in range(0, 30):
             this_x = Q
             this_y = sum(Z(Q))
             x.append(this_x)
             y.append(this_y)
             csv_writer.writerow((this_x, this_y))
```

Comment: can't understand a thing. looks like an excerpt from some prior discussion - but I'm no telepathist to deduce the missing bits.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev  You are right! I posted another question related to that initially, and get solved. But I met trouble into new ones. So, post once more...

Comment: @Chenxi: you will have multiple `Q` and  `sum(z(q))` for each line that you are reading from `csv`- Correct?. How are you planning to store those on a single line? , may be comma seperated?

Comment: @Chenxi:  Since you are using `3*Order_Number` , you will have that many values of Q and `sum(z(Q))`. so you need to plan for that. may be find mean/median?  You can print at critical lines to see the data output.

Comment: Thank you！@Anil_M Right, as you said, there would be multiple pairs `Q, Z(Q)` for each (Factory / Product_Number / Date / mu / cs / co) combination and I would like to store it into a csv file just add two more columns to prior input file, is that doable?

Comment: @Anil_M Sorry, I think you are right, and that is not efficient. I changed my post on the last part for the output data, kind of transpose. Thanks!

Comment: @Chenxi : do you know max value of  N for `Q = N` columns ahead of time. Because , if you do row by row and have N higher later, it will put values but will not have header. Things will be complicated if N is dynamic. Unless you can fix to some max value.

Comment: @Anil_M Thanks for your reminding. I changed N to 30 to make it more direct. And 30 is enough for my case.

Comment: @Chenxi :yes, with a fix value of N , it should be lot simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, Here is the solution.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import poisson, norm
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict


def Z(Q,p,cs,co):
    for i in range(len(p)):
        yield p[i]*cs*max((Q-i), 0) + p[i]*co*max((i-Q), 0)


# Read Data
with open('r2.csv', 'r') as infile , open("output.csv",'wb') as resultFile:    
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(resultFile,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    header_written = False

    for row in reader:
        row_data = {}
        out_data = OrderedDict()
        for header, value in row.items():
            header = header.strip()
            value = value.strip()
            try:
                row_data[header].append(''.join(value))
            except KeyError:
                row_data[header] = ''.join(value)

        #Process row data        
        mu = float(''.join(row_data['mu']))
        cs = float(''.join(row_data['cs']))
        co = float(''.join(row_data['co']))

        # Obtain Order_Number 
        Order_Number =np.ceil(poisson.ppf(co/(cs+ co), mu))

        #Add titles to out dict
        for title in 'Factory','Product_Number','Date','mu','cs','co':
            out_data[title]=row_data[title]

        G = poisson(mu)
        p = G.pmf(np.arange(3*mu))

        # Q and sum_z_q calcs
        for Q in range(0, 30):
            sum_z_q = round(sum(Z(Q,p,cs,co)), 3)
            row_data["Q={}".format(Q)]= sum_z_q
            out_data["Q={}".format(Q)]= sum_z_q

        #Write header only once
        if header_written == False:
            header = out_data.keys()
            writer.writerow(out_data.keys()) # write headers
            header_written = True

        #Write values
        writer.writerow(out_data.values()) #write rows
        del out_data  #del object
        del row_data #del dict object
```

**Output CSV**
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help!  @Anil_M

Comment: Glad to help. If you like my both solutions upvote would be good. It shows value for solutions. Just click up-arrow next to my answers.